# How to prevent TextView from resizing its container

Tags: android, layout, textview

Take a look at my layout
http://pastebin.com/6tQVm3Rk

My problem is that the textviews (named header1 to 5) are resizing its containers when a certain amount of letters are written into it, although there is still some space left.

What changes do I have to make that the layout stays in its original state independent from the amount of text located in the headers?

Comment: example screenshot: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/508/exampletk.png/

Comment: finally i made it, i wonder why i did not find the solution earlier -.-.

setting width and height of the textviews to wrap_content and the gravity of the container to center brought the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of this attribute.

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

If you want your textview to have only one line you can use `android:singleline="true"`

Comment: no, that is intended in case of that the text is longer then the view.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute

```
android:maxLength="2"
```

to the textview. This way you can limit the number of characters.

Comment: but why should i limit the number of letters when there is still some space left?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use **Relative layout** instead **Linear layout** in the XML so that objects in **Relative layout** are easy to manage dynamically, all you need to do is that put all those text views in the **Relative layout** and set these parameters:

**layout align left:** 
**layout align right:**

And other solution which is not appropriate is that fix the size of text view then it will not expand.

[*And please see the Documentation for further details of **Relative Layout**.*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and heigth of your textview to a fixed amount of dp. This will prevent the textview from streching beyond the width and height you declared. Like this:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_heigth="50dp"
```

Comment: that would be possible, but i do not really like to set hardcoded values for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to use

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

together with

```
android:maxLines="1"
```